# Android Retrofit parse xml

Tags: android, xml, parsing, xml-parsing, retrofit

I'm just starting to work with Retrofit. How can I parse the following XML:

```
<WTF>
 <RT fast="3">
  <NEW i="98" frag="S" gs="0" gm="1">
   <CRC desc="08" bad="01">
    <XYZ po="77"/>
    <PARSE max="7" min="1"/>
   </CRC>
   <CRC desc="08" bad="01">
    <XYZ po="65"/>
    <PARSE max="5" min="4"/>
   </CRC>
   <CRC desc="09" bad="01">
    <XYZ po="23"/>
    <PARSE max="7" min="5"/>
   </CRC>
   <CRC desc="09" bad="01">
    <XYZ po="47"/>
    <PARSE max="6" min="0"/>
   </CRC>
  </NEW>
 </RT>
</WTF>
```

*That's what I'm doing:*

**First, I added in the Retrofit Gradle:**

```
compile ('com.squareup.retrofit:converter-simplexml:2.0.0-beta2') {
            exclude group: 'xpp3', module: 'xpp3'
            exclude group: 'stax', module: 'stax-api'
            exclude group: 'stax', module: 'stax'
}
```

**Then, in the main Activity I added :**

```
 try {
            String xmlData = getXmlFromUrl(url);
            //xmlData here I successfully got xml
            Serializer serializer = new Persister();

            Reader reader = new StringReader(xmlData);
            XML osd =   serializer.read(XML.class, reader, false);
            Log.d(TAG, "-----" +osd.toString());

        } 
        catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "ERROR", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
```

**In XML class:**

```
@Root(name = "WTF")
public class XML {

    @ElementList(name = "RT")
    public List<RT> rt;


    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        builder.append(rt);
        return builder.toString();
    }
}
```

I inherits from classes

**In RT class:**

```
@Root(name = "RT")

public class RT {

        @ElementList(name = "NEW")
        public List<NEW> nw;


        @Override
        public String toString() {
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            builder.append(nw);
            return builder.toString();
        }
}
```

But unfortunately I keep getting an error.

Comment: bug appears here:  catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "ERROR", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

Comment: returns null. I need to get the attributes i, frag,gs, gm 
and so on: ... <NEW i="98" frag="S" gs="0" gm="1"> .... and how to do it I have not found

Comment: More so I try to get the attributes .  @Attribute(name = "frag", empty = "not data", required = false)
    public String frag; But constantly returns not data  
and so , too, I tried required = true

Comment: really nobody knows???